# No se muestran mis entradas de categoría

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola comunidad tengo una duda:

He creado un `custom post` con sus respectivos campos personalizados, todo esto es para agregar información acerca de "`magias`" (mi pagina trata de un juego particular).

He logrado mostrar la información de cada magia en una página única llamada `single-magia.php`, en la cual se muestran las particularidades de una magia determinada, hasta ahí todo bien, he podido agregar información de otras magias y cada una se muestra correctamente en la plantilla `single-magia.php`.

Ahora el problema...

Resulta que tengo una pagina personalizada llamada "`Magias`" que es donde deberán aterrizar todas las magias que forman parte de la categoría "magias". En esta página aparecerá un enlace de cada magia y al abrirlo este mostrará la información de esa magia en su `single-magia.php`

Pero...

En la pagina personalizada de Magias, en vez de mostrar las paginas que pertenecen a la categoria "`magias`", muestra son las entradas, es decir, solamente aparecen las páginas de publicaciones de mis entradas que no forman parte de la categoría magias.

En mi página single-magia.php tengo esto ([He aquí la pagina][1]):

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <!-- Entrada -->
          <div class="col-12 pt-2">
          <?php the_field('nombre'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('palabra_magica'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('vocacion'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('nivel'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('grupo'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('cooldown_de_magia'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('cooldown_de_grupo'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('premium'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('mana_requerida'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('efecto'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('adicion'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('notas'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('historia'); ?> <br>
          <?php the_field('donde_comprar'); ?> <br><br>
          <?php the_category(); ?>
          </div>
          <!-- End Entrada -->
  <?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Y de manera correcta me muestra la información de cada magia que voy agregando. Esta es la página unica de cada magia. Ahí todo bien...

Ahora en mi pagina personalizada de magias llamada `t_page_magias.php` tengo lo siguiente ([He aquí la pagina de attrerizaje][2]):

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Magias
*/
?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'in_category' => 'magias', 'posts_per_page' => 300 ) ); 
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_field('nombre'); ?>
<?php the_field('palabra_magica'); ?>
<?php the_field('premium'); ?>
<?php the_field('voacion'); ?>
<?php the_field('nivel'); ?>
         
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

En teoría creo que `'in_category' => 'magias'` deberia mostrar todas las paginas de la categoria `'magias'` pero no lo hace, solamente muestra mis entradas de la pagina principal que nada tienen que ver con magias. Parece que hay algo que estoy omitiendo pero no se que es.

¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: creaste publicaciones o paginas? las paginas no tienen categorias, las publicaciones si...

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Mi error estaba en 'in_category' => 'magias', tuve que cambiarlo a 'post_type' => 'magia', 'in_category' => 'magias' para elegir el tipo de publicación (muy importante), en mi caso es de tipo "magia" y también para seleccionar los posts dentro de la categoria "magias".

Ahora sí muestra todo de forma correcta. He agregado algunas magias nuevas y cada una abre en single-magia.php y al mismo tiempo se muestran todas las publicaciones de la categoria "Magias"  en mi pag de aterrizaje: t_page_magias.php 
Con esto doy por cerrado el tema! Saludos!

Comment: entonces ponelo como respuesta... aclara el problema yla solucion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encontré la solución**

En un principio el problema estaba en que no podía mostrar publicaciones personalizadas en una determinada página, ya que no había elegido el tipo de publicación a mostrar.

La solución fue modificar un poco el loop:

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'magia', 'in_category' => 'magias', 'posts_per_page' => 700 ) ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Dónde:**

*`post_type => magia,`* es el tipo de post. Corresponde al nombre del tipo de publicación que se ha creado. En mi caso estoy usando CPT UI, y el post type es el nombre que se le da al tipo de publicación.

Según acabo de ver y es lo lógico, es de vital importancia colocar el post type, de ese modo WordPress sabrá a qué clase de publicación pertenece la búsqueda.

*`in_category => magias,`* es la categoría a la cual pertenece la publicación, en este caso pertenece a la categoría magias (no confundir con magia (en singular) del post type).

Entonces quedamos así:

WordPress busca el tipo de publicación "magia" y dentro de ese tipo de publicaciones busca los que pertenecen a la categoría "magias":

```
<?php 
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'magia', 'in_category' => 'magias', 'posts_per_page' => 700 ) ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

...

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Agregamos lo que vamos a agregar dentro del loop y listo, tenemos todas las publicaciones del tipo  y categoría elegidos.